# Problem while calculating BoundingBoxes on Mat object using pytorch mobile [Kotlin]

Tags: android-studio, opencv, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I'm using opencv with pytorch mobile to do object detection on a video frame with my trained Yolov5 MODEL with number of classes 2,
I have convert ByteBuffer frame (coming from JNI) into OpenCV MAT object and then get FloatArray from Tensor, now i want to get detection results from pre-defined methods [outputsToNMSPredictions](https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/blob/8e2700a96dd4126f7aaae0f62d52d44bac9ed722/ObjectDetection/app/src/main/java/org/pytorch/demo/objectdetection/PrePostProcessor.java), the Bounding Boxes are not correctly mapped on the Mat object and most of time giving indexOutOfBound exception,

I have tried to get solutions from Stackoverflow but unable to find any helping material about my specific query.
here is demo project i'm using [android-demo-app](https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/tree/8e2700a96dd4126f7aaae0f62d52d44bac9ed722/ObjectDetection)

i have tried this [demo-project](https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/tree/8e2700a96dd4126f7aaae0f62d52d44bac9ed722/ObjectDetection) for help,

my current code for calculating bounding boxes is here

**MainActivityCode:**

```
override fun onImageProcessingMain(data: ByteBuffer): ByteArray {

        val color = Scalar(0.0, 0.0, 255.0) // BGR
        val thickness = 2

        val inputBytes = ByteArray(data.remaining())
        data.get(inputBytes)

        val imgRgb = Imgcodecs.imdecode(MatOfByte(*inputBytes), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR)
        val imgBgr = Mat()
        val img = Mat(720, 1280, CvType.CV_8UC3, data)
        // Convert RGB To BGR
        cvtColor(img, imgBgr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        // Convert BGR To RGB
        cvtColor(imgBgr, imgRgb, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        val resizedImg = Mat()
        Imgproc.resize(imgRgb, resizedImg, Size(640.0, 640.0))


        val inputTensor = matToFloat32TensorFun(
            resizedImg
        )
        val outputTuple = mModule?.forward(IValue.from(inputTensor))?.toTuple()

        val outputTensor = outputTuple?.get(0)?.toTensor()
        val outputs = outputTensor?.dataAsFloatArray

        mResults = PrePostProcessor.outputsToNMSPredictions(outputs!!)

             for (result in mResults) {
                 val pttl = Point(result.rect.left.toDouble(), result.rect.top.toDouble())
                 val ptbr = Point(
                     (result.rect.left + TEXT_WIDTH).toDouble(),  // result.rect.height(),
                     (result.rect.top +  TEXT_HEIGHT).toDouble()  //result.rect.width()
                 )
                 val rec = Rect(result.rect.left,result.rect.top,
                     result.rect.left+result.rect.width() ,result.rect.top+result.rect.height()
                 )


                 Imgproc.rectangle(imgRgb, rec, color, thickness)
                 //Imgproc.rectangle()
           

                 Imgproc.putText(
                     imgRgb,
                     String.format("%s %.2f", PrePostProcessor.mClasses[result.classIndex], result.score),
                     pttl,
                     Core.COVAR_NORMAL,
                     2.0,
                     Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0),
                     1
                 )
             }
        cvtColor(imgRgb, imgBgr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        val outputBytes = ByteArray(imgBgr.total().toInt() * imgBgr.channels())
        imgBgr.get(0, 0, outputBytes)
        val mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgRgb.cols(), imgRgb.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        Utils.matToBitmap(imgRgb, mBitmap)
        runOnUiThread{
            mImageView?.setImageBitmap(mBitmap)
        }


        return outputBytes

    }
```

**Calculate Predictions function:**

````
fun outputsToNMSPredictionsMat(outputs: FloatArray): ArrayList<Result> {
        val results = ArrayList<Result>()
        val imgWidth = 640
        val imgHeight = 640
        val startX = 0
        val startY = 0
        val mOutputColumn = 7 // left, top, right, bottom, score, and 2 class probabilities

        for (i in 0 until mOutputRow) {
            if ((i * PrePostProcessor.mOutputColumn + 4) < 176400) { // this line added by me prevent indexoutofbound error 
                if (outputs[i * mOutputColumn + 4] > mThreshold) {
                    val x = outputs[i * mOutputColumn]
                    val y = outputs[i * mOutputColumn + 1]
                    val w = outputs[i * mOutputColumn + 2]
                    val h = outputs[i * mOutputColumn + 3]

                    // Calculate the coordinates relative to the Mat dimensions
                    val left = startX + (x - w / 2) * imgWidth
                    val top = startY + (y - h / 2) * imgHeight
                    val right = startX + (x + w / 2) * imgWidth
                    val bottom = startY + (y + h / 2) * imgHeight

                    var max = outputs[i * mOutputColumn + 5]
                    var cls = 0

                    innerloop@ for (j in 0 until PrePostProcessor.mOutputColumn - 5) {
                        val indx = i * PrePostProcessor.mOutputColumn + 5 + j
                        if (indx < 176400) { // this line added by me prevent indexoutofbound error 
                            if (outputs[i * PrePostProcessor.mOutputColumn + 5 + j] > max) {
                                max = outputs[i * PrePostProcessor.mOutputColumn + 5 + j]
                                cls = j
                            }
                        } else {
                            break@innerloop // this line added by me prevent indexoutofbound error 
                        }
                    }

                    val rect = Rect(
                        left.toInt(),
                        top.toInt(),
                        right.toInt(),
                        bottom.toInt()
                    )

                    val result = Result(cls, outputs[i * mOutputColumn + 4], rect)
                    results.add(result)
                }
            }
        }

        return nonMaxSuppression(results, mNmsLimit, mThreshold)
    }```



Im expecting a valid method/solution to calculate bounding boxes and then map correctly on Mat object
````

Answer (score 0):

according to the Mat/Image size , try using mImgScaleX,mImgScaleY, mIvScaleX, mIvScaleY, mStartX, mStartY with this method outputsToNMSPredictions mentioned in your above demo project

```
mImgScaleX = resizedImg.cols().toFloat().div(mInputWidth.toFloat())
mImgScaleY = resizedImg.rows().toFloat().div(mInputHeight.toFloat())

mIvScaleX =
    if (resizedImg.cols() > mInputWidth.toFloat()) 1080f / resizedImg.cols() else 1080f / resizedImg.rows()
mIvScaleY =
    if (resizedImg.rows() > mInputHeight.toFloat()) 1080f / resizedImg.rows() else 1080f / resizedImg.cols()

mStartX = (1080f - mIvScaleX * resizedImg.cols()) / 2
mStartY = (1080f - mIvScaleY * resizedImg.rows()) / 2

     mResults = PrePostProcessor.outputsToNMSPredictions(outputs!!,
         mImgScaleX,
         mImgScaleY,
         mIvScaleX,
         mIvScaleY,
         mStartX,
         mStartY)
```

Comment: I have tried your above code but its giving indexOutOfBoundException at this if statement
`if (outputs[i * PrePostProcessor.mOutputColumn + 5 + j] > max) {
                                max = outputs[i * PrePostProcessor.mOutputColumn + 5 + j]
                                cls = j
                            }`